# Repetitively taking XOR of consecutive elements

Tags: math, xor, bitwise-xor

Given a binary array of size `N`

```
e.g. A[1:N] = 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

A new array of size `N-1` will be created by taking `XOR` of 2 consecutive elements.

```
A'[1:N-1] = 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
```

Repeat this operation until one element is left.

```
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0
0 0 1
0 1
1
```

I want to find the last element left (`0` or `1`)

One can find the answer by repetitively performing the operation. This approach will take `O(N*N)` time. Is there a way to solve the problem more efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very efficient solution to this problem, which needs just a few lines of code, but it's rather complicated to explain. I'll have a go, anyway.

Suppose you need to reduce a list of, say, 6 numbers that are all zero except for one element. By symmetry, there are just three cases to consider:

```
1   0   0   0   0   0      0   1   0   0   0   0      0   0   1   0   0   0
  1   0   0   0   0          1   1   0   0   0          0   1   1   0   0
    1   0   0   0              0   1   0   0              1   0   1   0
      1   0   0                  1   1   0                  1   1   1
        1   0                      0   1                      0   0
          1                          1                          0
```

In the first case, a single '1' at the edge doesn't really do anything much. It basically just stays put. But in the other two cases, more elements of the list get involved and the situation is more complex. A '1' in the second element of the list produces a result of '1', but a '1' in the third element produces a result of '0'. Is there a simple rule that explains this behaviour?

Yes, there is. Take a look at this:

```
Row 0:             1
Row 1:           1   1
Row 2:         1   2   1
Row 3:       1   3   3   1
Row 4:     1   4   6   4   1
Row 5:   1   5   10  10  5   1
```

I'm sure you've seen this before. It's Pascal's triangle, where each row is obtained by adding adjacent elements taken from the row above. The larger numbers in the middle of the triangle reflect the fact that these numbers are obtained by adding together values drawn from a broader subset of the preceding rows.

Notice that in Row 5, the two numbers in the middle are both even, while the other numbers are all odd. This exactly matches the behaviour of the three examples shown above; the XOR product of an even number of '1's is zero, and the XOR product of an odd number of '1's is '1'.

To make things clearer, let's just consider the parity of the numbers in this triangle (i.e., '1' for odd numbers, '0' for even numbers):

```
Row 0:             1
Row 1:           1   1
Row 2:         1   0   1
Row 3:       1   1   1   1
Row 4:     1   0   0   0   1
Row 5:   1   1   0   0   1   1
```

This is actually called a [Sierpinski triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle). Where a zero appears in this triangle, it tells us that it doesn't matter if your list has a '1' or a '0' in this position; it will have no effect on the resulting value because if you wrote out the expression showing the value of the final result in terms of all the initial values in your list, this element would appear an even number of times.

Take a look at Row 4, for example. Every element is zero except at the extreme edges. That means if your list has 5 elements, the end result depends only on the first and last elements in the list. (The same applies to any list where the number of elements is one more than a power of 2.)

The rows of the Sierpinski triangle are easy to calculate. As mentioned in [oeis.org/A047999](https://oeis.org/A047999):

> Lucas's Theorem is that T(n,k) = 1 if and only if the 1's in the binary expansion of k are a subset of the 1's in the binary expansion of n; or equivalently, k AND NOT n is zero, where AND and NOT are bitwise operators.

---

So, after that long-winded explanation, here's my code:

```py
def xor_reduction(a):
    n, r = len(a), 0
    for k in range(n):
        b = 0 if k & -n > 0 else 1
        r ^= b & a.pop()
    return r

assert xor_reduction([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]) == 1
```

I said it was short. In case you're wondering, the 4th line has `k & -n` (k AND minus n) instead of `k & ~n` (k AND not n) because n in this function is the number of elements in the list, which is one more than the row number, and `~(n-1)` is the same thing as `-n` (in Python, at least).